# Want to extend main partition into unallocated space, but it is blocked

Tags: partitioning, ssd, ntfs, storage

I have an SSD with 763.8GB of unallocated space. I'm trying to extend my main partition into that unallocated space. However, it is blocked by a partition called *.IMAGE, which is 10GB. I don't know how to move or get rid of this IMAGE partition so I have access this free space.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. I extended the image partition to fill it with the unallocated space then shrunk it on the other side then extended the main partition.